# Producing an X any Y coordinate from a Lidar sensor

Tags: ros, ros2, coordinate-system, coordinate, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The project I am working on needs to track a ball on a 10' by 10' platform. I need to produce coordinates with the 2d lidar sensor I have. The sensor I have available to me is a Sick TIM561.

The platform is using ubuntu to run Linux with ROS

This is the first time I have worked with ROS and Python so any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I do have some experience working with arduino programming.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328200/producing-an-x-any-y-coordinate-from-a-lidar-sensor/) by [EricMt](https://answers.ros.org/users/44029/ericmt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-10**:
If you've never used ROS before then I'd recommend working through the tutorials first before jumping straight into a project like this. We're here you help but you need to try and find a solution and come to us with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you have received a LaserScan message you can access it's individual measurement. Because you know the resolution of your sensor you can calculate the angle for each measurement. With that angle and the distance that the measurement represents you can filter out anything that is part of the platform. You will then have a set of distances that correspond to the ball.

A detailed description of how to transform lidar measurements to coordinates can be found [here](https://hackernoon.com/lidar-basics-the-coordinate-system-a26529615df9) (in your case the z coordinate would be 0)

---

Originally posted by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) with karma: 140 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0